# Running more than one Future in Action.async

Tags: scala, playframework

I tried in this way but it always go to case Nil.

```
def findByLastName(lastName:String)=Action.async {
  val cursor = Json.obj("lastName" -> lastName)
  StudentDaoAndEntity.findAllStudent(cursor) flatMap { lastName =>
    ExaminationDao.findStudent(cursor) flatMap { lastName =>
      LibraryDao.findStudent(cursor) map {
        {
          case Nil => Ok("Student Not Found")
          case l: Seq[JsObject] => Ok(Json.toJson(l))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my defined functions in Database are:

In StudentDaoAndEntity:

```
def findAllStudent(allStd: JsObject): Future[Seq[JsObject]] = {
  // gather all the JsObjects in a list
  collection.find(allStd).cursor[JsObject].collect[List]()
}
```

In LibraryDao:

```
def findStudent(allStd: JsObject): Future[Seq[JsObject]] = {
  // gather all the JsObjects in a list
  collection.find(allStd).cursor[JsObject].collect[List]()
}
```

In ExaminationDao:

```
def findStudent(allStd: JsObject): Future[Seq[JsObject]] = {
  // gather all the JsObjects in a list
  collection.find(allStd).cursor[JsObject].collect[List]()
}
```

Comment: You're shadowing `lastName` twice. Also, you're not using either of them.

Comment: lastName is the field in every modules.

Comment: Keeping collection name of respective database in place of lastName works.Thank You @rethab

Comment: Are you hitting the database 3 times for something that could be one single query join ?

Comment: The 3 databases are not same, each time I am retrieving from different database. So I dont think it is possible with join for 3 different databases. @ALEX_AME

Comment: Alright got it,

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with shadowing the `lastName` argument inside each lambda (as comments already pointed out). That being said, you can use a for-comprehension to make your code more readable

```
def findByLastName(lastName:String) = Action.async {
  val cursor = Json.obj("lastName" -> lastName)
  for {
    _ <- StudentDaoAndEntity.findAllStudent(cursor)
    _ <- ExaminationDao.findStudent(cursor)
    students <- LibraryDao.findStudent(cursor)
  } yield students match {
    case Nil => Ok("Student Not Found")
    case l: Seq[JsObject] => Ok(Json.toJson(l))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I want:

```
def findByLastName(lastName:String)=Action.async {
  request =>

  val cursor = Json.obj("lastName" -> lastName)

  StudentDaoAndEntity.findAllStudent(cursor) flatMap {
    student =>

    ExaminationDao.findStudent(cursor) flatMap {
      examination =>

      LibraryDao.findStudent(cursor) map {
        {
          case Nil => Ok("Student Not Found")

          case library: Seq[JsObject] =>
            val finalResult = student ++ examination ++ library
            Ok(JsArray(finalResult))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```